# Does SQLBrite close cursor automatically?

Tags: android, sqlbrite

I have the doubt to wether sqlbrite close cursor automatically, it seems that it doesn't do it since I keep getting :

> java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called at
>   dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:809)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)

but I don't see anything in [docs](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite) stating that I should be explicitly call `cursor.close`.

## Edit 1

Here is a snippet of what is giving me a cursor not close error:

```
DbProvider.db(getActivity()).createQuery(Item.NAME, sqlQuery, selectionArgs).mapToList(new Func1<Cursor, ItemEntity>() {
    @Override
    public ItemEntity call(Cursor cursor) {
        return new ItemEntity(cursor);
    }
}).subscribe(itemEntities -> {
    Debug.info(this, "items " + itemEntities );
}, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling `query.run()` and getting a cursor you need to close it manually. If you are using the `mapToList`/`mapToOne` api's you do not need to close it manually.

Comment: The issue was that I was using loader API before calling `db.createQuery` because I am migrating the code to sqlbrite, so it seem there was a raise condition there that threw an error.

Comment: Official answer from a github issue in sqlitebrite: https://github.com/square/sqlbrite/issues/94